# Help with math term "stability of convergence".

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

There is a theorem in my textbook (not on English). The theorem states the following:

**We have a sequence of measurable functions $f_k$. They are finite almost everywhere on the set $E\subset X$ where $\mu E< +\infty$. $f_k\rightarrow 0$ almost everywhere on $E$. Then there is exists an increasing sequence of positive numbesrs $\lambda_k\rightarrow +\infty$ such that $\lambda_k f_k(x)\rightarrow 0$ almost everywhere on $E$.**

Then there is written that this property is called ..."stability of convergence"...or something like that. I can not search this term in Google.

Question: can someone say what is this property on English? Or can some one promt where I can find it?

Comment: This does not solve you problem completely but my be useful. A well known result in topological linear spaces states that 
> Theorem: Suppose $X$ is a topological linear space whose topology is generated by an invariant metric $d$ (normed spaces and Frechet's spaces for example). For any sequence $\{x_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset X$, if $x_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbf{0}$, then there exists a sequence of scalars $\gamma_n$ with $|\gamma_n|\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\infty$ such that $\gamma_n\,x_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbf{0}$.

Comment: If convergence almost surely is change by convergence in probability, then the Theorem applies for convergence in probability can be topologize by metric $d(X,Y)=E[|X-Y|\wedge1]$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thanks! It is very usefull! Which book you would recomend to read in which I will find this theorem (theorem in your comment)?

Comment: That result can be found in Rudin’s book on functional analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mu(E)<\infty$, $g_n\to 0$ a.e. on $E$ iff $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(\{E:\sup_{m\ge n}|g_m|>\epsilon\})= 0$ for any $\epsilon>0$. Now, construct a sequence $\{\lambda_n\}$ recursively. Set $\lambda_n=k^{-1}$ for $N_k\le n< N_{k+1}$, where $N_k$ is s.t.
$$
\mu\left(\left\{E:\sup_{n\ge N_k}|f_n|>k^{-1}\right\}\right)<k^{-1}.
$$

Comment: Thanks! I asked does this property have any name. I think I will not get the answer. But either way I will accept this answer.